# ¿Cómo graficar series de tiempo con 3 (o más) ejes Y de distintas escalas?

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2, gráficas

Estoy tratando de graficar una serie de tiempo, con 3 paneles (paralelos al eje X), cada panel con distintas escalas:

```
data.frame(fecha = c(1 ,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14), temperatura = c(25.0, 26.7, 26.6, 25.2, 25.1, 27.6, 27.0, 28.8, 26.2, 24.3, 24.4, 24.8, 24.7, 26.3), humedad_rel = c(88.8, 86.7, 86.1, 86.4, 86.9, 88.7, 89.1, 85.8, 90.9, 88.0, 85.7, 87.4, 84.9, 84.9),  fluctuacion_tronco = c(297.7, 278.9, 251.7, 231.3, 270.9, 346.4, 342.1, 331.7, 370.0, 283.5, 186.4, 255.6, 189.5, 193.0))
```

Como ven tengo 3 escalas distintas (grados cent, porcentaje y micras), y estoy tratando de obtener algo parecido a:

[image: gráfica ejemplo]

Ayuda por favor!

Comment: Bienvenido Sergio Javier Ayaque Cruz a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es muy poca la información para obtener algo como lo que comentas. Pero una aproximación es usando `ggplot`.

Primero debes preparar tus datos para graficarlos según el formato preferido por `ggplot` utilizando la función `gather()` de `tidyr`:

```
df <- data.frame(fecha = c(1 ,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14), temperatura = c(25.0, 26.7, 26.6, 25.2, 25.1, 27.6, 27.0, 28.8, 26.2, 24.3, 24.4, 24.8, 24.7, 26.3), humedad_rel = c(88.8, 86.7, 86.1, 86.4, 86.9, 88.7, 89.1, 85.8, 90.9, 88.0, 85.7, 87.4, 84.9, 84.9),  fluctuacion_tronco = c(297.7, 278.9, 251.7, 231.3, 270.9, 346.4, 342.1, 331.7, 370.0, 283.5, 186.4, 255.6, 189.5, 193.0))

library(tidyr)

df <- gather(data = df, key = 'Variable', value = 'Valor', -fecha)
```

Luego, graficarlos con `ggplot()`. La función `facet_wrap()` dividirá el gráfico en diferentes paneles en base a las variables utilizadas, el resto son mejoras gráficas:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = fecha, y = Valor)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0),
                     breaks = df$fecha, minor_breaks = NULL) +
  facet_wrap(~Variable,nrow = 3,scales = 'free_y',
             strip.position = "left", 
             labeller = as_labeller(c(fluctuacion_tronco = "Fluctuación tronco (¿mm?)", 
                                      humedad_rel = "Humedad relativa (%)",
                                      temperatura = "Temperatura (ºC)"))) +
  ylab(NULL) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias Aldo!